# How can I make multiple scales for boxplots in python?

Tags: python, boxplot, multiple-axes

I am trying to use the matplotlib boxplot to show the boxplot of a number of distributions.  One group of distributions is on a very different scale than the other group.  I have been trying to use twinx() to plot the second group but it overlaps with the other boxplots.
Is there a better method to add a different scale for specific data?